# Unable to link to GraphicsMagik

Tags: c++, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to build a little utility program that relies upon GraphicsMagick C++ library but I got the following error when linking to the library:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ale/sample'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ale/sample/src'
g++  -g -O2   -o mysample mysample-a.o -L/usr/local/lib -lexiv2   -L/usr/local/lib -lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick    
/usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-png.o): In function `png_put_data':
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1171: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
/usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-png.o): In function `PNGWarningHandler':
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1357: undefined reference to `png_error'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1361: undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
/usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-png.o): In function `PNGErrorHandler':
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1338: undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr'
/usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-png.o): In function `png_get_data':
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1060: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1076: undefined reference to `png_warning'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1077: undefined reference to `png_error'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:1067: undefined reference to `png_warning'
/usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-png.o): In function `png_write_raw_profile':
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:6243: undefined reference to `png_malloc'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:6253: undefined reference to `png_malloc'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:6254: undefined reference to `png_malloc'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:6281: undefined reference to `png_set_text'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:6282: undefined reference to `png_free'
/home/ale/Downloads/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18/coders/png.c:6283: undefined reference to `png_free'
```

Why does the library in /usr/local/lib refers to GraphicsMagick source code (that I've built and installed)?

Answer (score 0):

Errors says that you need to link with libpng too.

You having very descriptive source-code related errors because you've built graphicsmagick with debugging symbols. In release build (or if you'll strip debugging symbols out of debug build) you'll see only undefined function names, without source code references of where they're being used.